# I'm getting an error while reading a csv with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting this error while I'm trying to read a csv in python with pandas

```
df02 = pd.read_csv('PMDM Full\filename.csv', sep = '|') 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
"C:\Users\dm\Google Drive\CS\GV\Tickets\Status
Check\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in
wrapper   File "C:\Users\dm\Google Drive\CS\GV\Tickets\Status
Check\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250,
in read    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)   File
"C:\Users\dm\Google Drive\CS\GV\Tickets\Status
Check\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py",
line 225, in read    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)  
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory   File
"pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows  File
"pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in
pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows   File
"pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in
pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error pandas.errors.ParserError:
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 109 fields in line 1021, saw
113
```

Code used:

```
df02 = pd.read_csv('filepath', sep = '|')
```

[sample file](https://www.file.io/T1XS/download/SolBfXUdmDFx)

Comment: `Expected 109 fields in line 1021, saw 113` I'm not sure we can tell you much more than what the error message already gives you.

Comment: A sample of the file you're attempting to read would help in determining the source of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because line 5 of the csv contains a different number of columns than the other lines.
To read the file excluding this line you can use the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep='|', error_bad_lines=False)
```